# Mapper task completion event

Tags: hadoop, hbase

We have a map reduce task set up on HBase. I have a requirement that I need to know once a mapper instantiated by the framework completes its task.

Is there any event that I have to look upon? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add some more details of the problem? Like, after the mapper finishes, exactly what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Like once the mapper is done with its work, I need to dump some data thats held in that mapper to a store. For e.g.. If mapper is keping track of all the keys that it is mapping and along with that some information (say some business logic) I want to dump it to a file once the mapper completes its task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dump that data inside the **cleanup()** method. cleanup() gets called for the mappers once they are done with everything so it should serve the purpose, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Tariq's answer, you can actually override the setup() and cleanup() methods from the Mapper class. So, for each map task, the cleanup() method gets called once at the end.
Please, do your final processing there.